# mixing $(this) value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to prevent mixing values in jquery if i use $(this)? For example:

```
1: <input type="text" id="in1" class="test"> <br />
2: <input type="text" id="in2" class="test"> <br />

<div id="ppp"> <p class="show" id="one">onevalue</p> <p class="show" id="two">twovalue</p></div>

#ppp {
    display: none;
}

$(".click").click(function(e) {

    $("#block").show();

    var current = $(this);

    $(".show").click(function(e) {
        current.val($(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

live example - http://jsfiddle.net/VmXU9/59/

If i clicked in 1 input show me "onevalue" and "twovalue". If i clicked "onevalue" or "twovalue" that in 1 input appears id of "onevalue" or "twovalue". This is good, but if i additionally clickes 2 input and choose "onevalue" or "twovalue" that ID of "onevalue" or "twovalue" appears in 1 input and 2 intput. Should be only in one - in last clicked. How can i it make?

Thanks!

Comment: You should not re-jquery this ofcourse: var current = $(this);
current.val(this.attr("id"));

Comment: I'm having trouble with your English, so i can't give you perfect advice, but it sounds like you would benefit from `.each()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: I don't think a down vote was appropriate for this question. It is a valid question, but the OP seems to struggle with English. Certainly that can't be held against him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you need to:

1. Move the scope of `current`
2. Move the binding of the click event on `input.show` elements to outside the click of `input.click` elements:

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/VmXU9/65/

Ideally, you'd close the scope over all of this to avoid introducing `current` as global, and you'd check that `current` had been changed from its initial setting before operating on it:

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/VmXU9/66/

Answer (score 1):

You're binding the `$(".show").click()` every time an input is clicked, causing it to duplicate. Make sure to unbind it first:

```
$(".show").unbind('click').click(function(e) {
 //etc
});
```

Comment: It is not advisable to call `unbind` of `click` before every `bind` of `click`. You could damage event handling which other code set up, and it is not the best thing for performance.  A scope adjustment and re-arrangment of logic will fix it without the need for unbind.

Comment: You're right. A better way would probably be to store a reference to the 'active' input somewhere, a data attribute of their container for instance, and use that reference inside the `$(".show").click()`. That way you can move that out of the `$(".click").click()` as well, reducing the amount of binds to just the initial ones.

Answer (score 0):

you have to unbind the the click for the .show.
add:

```
$('.show').unbind('click');
```

as in the example linked to below

live example - http://jsfiddle.net/VmXU9/62/

Comment: Please see my first comment on @Björn's answer.

Comment: There no indication that hes binding other click events to the item, and seems unlikely from the given examples.

Comment: *"There no indication that hes binding other click events to the item"* IMO, that's exactly the point. With programmatic assignment of event handlers, you would never have such an indication until the `unbind` started causing bugs. At the very least, if using `unbind`, one should use name-spaced events. That said, I still don't think it is a performant solution--that topic has been discussed on several jQuery podcasts, blogs, and forums. I don't mean to be demeaning, though, just offering my thoughts on the matter.

Comment: My point is this guy is a beginner, you can't teach best practices to someone who doesn't fundamentally understand the language.

Comment: Well then it definitely make sense to give him some code which could lead to issues which are extremely difficult to debug. /sarcasm